# Linking with library causes collate facet to be missing from char

Tags: c++14, ld, glibc

I have a C++14 application using `std::regex`.  For some regular expressions, the `std::regex` constructor will throw `std::bad_cast` (via `std::use_facet`) if the collate facet is not available.

I want to link my application with a third-party library distributed as a .so for which I do not have source.  This library gives default symbol versions on everything it needs from glibc.  The version it specifies is 2.2.5 (released in 2002).  For example, nm tells me:

```
U setlocale@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

If I link my application without the third-party library, regular expressions work.  But when I link with the third-party library, `std::has_facet<std::collate<char>>(std::locale())` returns false, so the `std::regex` constructor throws.

My guess is that the very old symbol versions desired by the third-party library are interfering with the default locale.  I have tried changing the default locale from within my application, but that does not help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Updating to a version of the third-party library built with a newer compiler causes the problem to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same Problem. In my case the behaviour occurred because I used **different versions of GCC** to compile library and executable. Here are my results of combining GCC 4.7 and GCC 5.5 to compile library and executable:

- Library (GCC 4.7) + Executable (GCC 5.5) = Failure: Collate missing
- Library (**GCC 4.7**) + Executable (**GCC 4.7**) = **Success**: Collate available
- Library (**GCC 5.5**) + Executable (**GCC 5.5**) = **Success**: Collate available

The test is based on checking the availability of the char collate like

```
std::has_facet<std::collate<char>>(std::locale())
```